# How to use arrays for comparisons using lambdas in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to know whether there is any way to **shorten** a comparison in lambdas by using arrays containing the comparison elements, instead of writing the elements one by one.

In practice, I have a `Dictionary<K,V>` variable named **litemList** already filled with data. I would like to have another `Dictionary<K,V>` variable with just some of the **Keys** of **litemList**.

```
lfilteredItemlist = litemList.Where(m => m.Key == "Name", m.Key == "Surname")
                             .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);
```

This code works perfectly but when I have 10 or more **Keys** to filter and they might change with time (or even selected by the users), this solution is not feasible.
I am looking for some solution where, assuming there is an array withall the Keys to filter, I can use something like this:

```
filterArray = {"Name", "Surname"};

lfilteredItemlist = litemList.Where(m => m.Key == filterArray)
                             .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);
```

I am quite sure that there is a method because once I saw it when looking for material about [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Unfortunately I cannot find the article again and [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) does not mention it in his blog.

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about changing the code to this:

```
lfilteredItemlist = litemList.Where(m => filterArray.Contains(m.Key))
                         .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);
```

Comment: To tune things a little bit, you could use a HashSet<string> instead of an array.

Comment: @ba__friend: he's talking about an array of size 10, even if it was 300 times bigger and ran on a mobile device it would still be fast enough.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthe: Thanks! That's the solution I was looking for